# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions - returned Image has a unwanted border

Tags: ios, swift

I used the function below to render Image, but the returned image had an unwanted border at bottom.

```
public func renderTextOnView(view: UIView) -> UIImage? {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0)

    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img
}
```

Then I change `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0)` to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, true, 0)` and the white border disappeared.

Though the issue has been fixed, I'm still confused, why is that changing  `false` to `true` remove the border? what happened behind it?

[image]

Comment: My guess is that you have an alpha channel on your image. If you remove the alpha, the last line becomes visible.

Comment: is the image filled your view ?

Answer (score 2):

check the syntax of it. it is,

```
func UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_ size: CGSize, _ opaque: Bool, _ scale: CGFloat).
```

So, you are changing opaque that's why it's happening. refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) for more detail. It is saying about opaque,

> A Boolean flag indicating whether the bitmap is opaque. If you know the bitmap is fully opaque, specify YES to ignore the alpha channel and optimize the bitmap’s storage. Specifying NO means that the bitmap must include an alpha channel to handle any partially transparent pixels.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: So I have something not fully opaque on the View? But the text("double tap to edit") I draw on the image is also not fully opaque, I set its alpha property to something like 0.6 or 0.8. Why is it still visible on the returned image?

Comment: becuase alpha is 0.6 or 0.8. set alpha 0 it will not visible

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the image of imageView cause the problem. I tried some other images, test with opaque set to false or true. Some of them had the white border no matter what the opaque is, Some of them looks good even I set opaque to false.(However, set opaque to true did fix the issue in my question).That's quite strange.

To conclude, setting the value of opaque doesn't guarantee to work(but work sometimes)